# tableView outlet nil when loading a table

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `tabBarController` and two `UINavigationControllers` with `UITableViews` attached to the `tabBarController`. I have subclassed the `tabBarController` so I can pass an array of custom objects between the two tables by reference. However, when I go to populate the array, the `tableView` outlet is unwrapping to nil and I am getting the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Not sure why this is happening. Below is the code:

**tabBarController**

```
protocol CustomTabBarDelegate {
var placeDataArray : Array <placeData> {get set}
}

class placeData: Equatable {
var description : String
var selected : Bool

init (description : String, selected : Bool) {
    self.description = description
    self.selected = selected
}
}

class PlacesTabBarController: UITabBarController {

var placeDataArray = Array<placeData>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    placeDataArray = [placeData(description: "Afghanistan", selected: false), placeData(description: "Albania", selected: false)]

    var table1 = AllPlacesViewController()
    var table2 = AttendingPlacesTableViewController()

    table1.delegate = self
    table2.delegate = self

    var navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table1)
    var navController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table2)

    self.viewControllers = [navController1, navController2]
    }
}
```

**tableViewControllers**

```
var delegate:PlacesTabBarController!
```

and then, for instance, I can access the array by calling

```
delegate.placeDataArray.count
```

When I go to populate the table with

```
@IBOutlet weak var allPlacesTableView: UITableView!
```

and use

```
 var cell = self.allPlacesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
```

The error mentioned above is thrown. Not sure why `allPlacesTableView` is unwrapping to nil

Comment: did you connect your outlet to tableview?

Comment: where is the error happening

Comment: Yes, the `tableView` is connected to the outlet and the error is happening right when the `UITableViewController` loads. As soon as the `tableView` loads and tries to populate the cells it errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create your VCs like this,

```
var table1 = AllPlacesViewController()
```

they are not linked to the storyboard, so the outlets are not fulfilled.  Use the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method of self.storyboard instead:

```
var table1 : AllPlacesViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AllPlaces") as AllPlacesViewController
```

Comment: I added the method in using `var table1:UITableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AllPlaces") as UITableViewController`. Does this take the place of any of the other code in the `viewDidLoad` function? or just the `table1` and `table2` variables. I am getting an error of "UITableViewController does not have a member named delegate" if I add in that method.

Comment: You just need to change the cast slightly - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You are not instantiating your ViewController properly. make sure if you're instantiating your VC from storybaord you are doing it like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let someVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as? SomeViewController
```